# Combining two ArrayList into an array only

Tags: java, arrays

So what I am trying to do is to combine two arraylists into one and write the file .csv based on the combined array/list.

Say, I have two ArrayList like these:

```
public static ArrayList<String> listingNameList;
public static ArrayList<String> listingPriceList;
```

I am trying to combine the `listingNameList` and `listingPriceList` into something called neededInfo. Then:

```
String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File file = new File(directory + "/src/sportsCardsTracker/CardPrices.csv");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false); //true to not over ride            for(String[] s : neededInfo){
            fw.write(s[0] + "," + s[1] +'\n');
            }
```

Currently I am not sure how to combined the `listingNameList` and `listingPriceList`. Or at least how may I write `listingNameList` and `listingPriceList` into the .csv file without having to combine the two? Any info and suggestion is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I have tried something like this, but it does not work. The for loop runs for 50 times because there are 50 items in `listingNameList` and 50 again in `listingPriceList`.

```
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            String[][] neededInfo = new String[2][i];
            neededInfo[0][i] = listingName_extract[i];
            neededInfo[1][i] = listingPrice_extract[i];
        }
        System.out.println(neededInfo);

    for(String[][] s : neededInfo){
        fw.write(s[0] + "," + s[1] +'\n');
        }
    fw.close();
```

Comment: What about replacing the returned type to String[][] ? That is a String array of String arrays. Or a collection (i.e. List) of String arrays.

Comment: I have tried that, but then I would not be able to use `add()` in adding items/arrays to `players`. :(

Answer (score 1):

What about having `String[][]`?

1. A list of pair [[name, price]]

```
private static String[][] parsingString(String listingName_temp, String listingPrice_temp) {
    String[] listingName_extract = listingName_temp.split("\\n");
    String[] listingPrice_extract = listingPrice_temp.split("\\n");
    String[][] nameAndPrice = new String[listingName_extract.length][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < listingName_extract.length; i++) {
        nameAndPrice[i][0] = listingName_extract[i];
        nameAndPrice[i][1] = listingPrice_extract[i];
    }
    return nameAndPrice;
}
```

Example

```
parsingString("name1\nname2\nname3", "1\n2\n3")

> [[name1, 1], [name2, 2], [name3, 3]]
```

2. A pair of lists [[names], [prices]]

```
private static String[][] parsingString(String listingName_temp, String listingPrice_temp) {
    String[] listingName_extract = listingName_temp.split("\\n");
    String[] listingPrice_extract = listingPrice_temp.split("\\n");
    String[][] nameAndPrice = new String[2][listingName_extract.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < listingName_extract.length; i++) {
        nameAndPrice[0][i] = listingName_extract[i];
        nameAndPrice[1][i] = listingPrice_extract[i];
    }
    return nameAndPrice;
}
```

Example

```
parsingString("name1\nname2\nname3", "1\n2\n3")

> [[name1, name2, name3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

**Edit** To write to the file you can use **"1. A list of pair [[name, price]]"** and the following steps

1. Open the file
2. Parse the data into a `String[][]`
3. Iterate the data and write it to the file
4. Close the file

```
private static String[][] parsingString(String listingName_temp, String listingPrice_temp) {
    String[] listingName_extract = listingName_temp.split("\\n");
    String[] listingPrice_extract = listingPrice_temp.split("\\n");
    String[][] nameAndPrice = new String[listingName_extract.length][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < listingName_extract.length; i++) {
        nameAndPrice[i][0] = listingName_extract[i];
        nameAndPrice[i][1] = listingPrice_extract[i];
    }
    return nameAndPrice;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("CardPrices.csv");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false); //true to not over ride
    String[][] players = parsingString("name1\nname2\nname3", "1\n2\n3");

    for (String[] s : players) {
        fw.write(s[0] + "," + s[1] + '\n');
    }
    fw.close();
}
```

Into the file you will have

```
name1,1
name2,2
name3,3
```

Comment: It did work, but unfortunately, I need to export the array to .csv file as well.

Comment: @kingkai I've added the export section

Comment: I think s should be `String[][]`, would that be correct? I am doing per your suggestions, but I got a mismatch (cannot convert from `String[][]` to `String[]`). However, even if I do `String[][]`, the output .csv file is empty. :(

Comment: @kingkai I've added the full main method. Make sure that you close the file `fw.close();`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to make a new array and then add all the value of both the array manually and then return,
if that is the case why not try like this

```
private static String[] parsingString(String listingName_temp, String listingPrice_temp) {
    String[] returnString_1 = null;
    String[] returnString_2 = null;
    String[] listingName_extract = listingName_temp.split("\\n");
    String[] listingPrice_extract = listingName_temp.split("\\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < listingName_extract.length; i++) {
        returnString_1[i] = listingName_extract[i];
        returnString_2[i] = listingPrice_extract[i];
    }
    return Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(returnString_1), Arrays.stream(returnString_2)).toArray();
}
```

Comment: It did work, but unfortunately, I need to export the array to .csv file as well.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I decided that combining the two would not be a good choice. Instead, I do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listingNameList.size(); i++) {
                fw.write(String.format("%s, %s\n", listingNameList.get(i), listingPriceList.get(i)));
            }
```